# Conectar un proyecto Java a Apache Solr 4.10.3

Tags: java, json, apache, rest

Tengo en Apache Solr 4.10.3 corriendo una colección llamada "Collection1". También tengo un proyecto en Maven por el momento completamente limpio y listo para armar. Lo primero que quiero hacer es conectar a Solr para obtener los datos indexados de Collection1. En internet hay muchos datos de como conectar a la base de datos pero, o no son muy claros, o no corresponde a la versión, o hacen una conexión sin apuntar a una colección en concreto:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.XMLResponseParser;

public class Connection {
    private static HttpSolrServer server;

    public static HttpSolrServer init() throws MalformedURLException{
        server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/");
        return server;
    }

}
```

¿Alguna idea de como conectar a Solr? Saludos.

**Actualización: encontré un código que puede funcionar, que agrega los parametros de la query por medio de setters, el problema es que no me reconoce el comando de throws para implementar las exception:**

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.XMLResponseParser;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.ModifiableSolrParams;

public class Connection throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException {
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("localhost:8983/solr/Collection1");


ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("qt", "/spellCheckCompRH");
params.set("q", "epod");
params.set("spellcheck", "on");
params.set("spellcheck.build", "true");

QueryResponse response = server.query(params);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, para conectar:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.XMLResponseParser;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.ModifiableSolrParams;

public class Connection {
public static HttpSolrServer server;
public static void init() throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException{
    server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/");
    server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
    }

}
```